# not able to display the contents of a file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, automation

I am trying to read the file content from a particular location in python, after entering the choice, it is not displaying any content and it is just coming out of a program, can anyone please guide me what is wrong with this code ?

```
import os
print('Please Enter the Choice and Press Enter')
print (' 1. Check for Version.xml \n 2. Check for PatchTool.log \n 3. Check for Logger ')

choice = input('Enter your choice: ')
if (choice == 1):
    version=open('d:\\pyhton\\abc.txt', 'r')
    ver = version.read()
    print(ver)

elif (choice == 2):
    xyz=open('d:\\pyhton\\xyz.txt', 'r')
    xyz1 = xyz.read()
    print(xyz1)

elif (choice == 3):
    de=open('d:\\pyhton\\def.txt', 'r')
    de1 = de.read()
    print(de1)

else:
    print('You entered the wrong Choice')
```

Comment: You are comparing `choice` against an `int` but the value from `input()` is a `str`. Try `if choice == '1':`.

Comment: Input is taken as string so first convert the input into int like choice=int(choice) then compare

Comment: Thank you, after adding quotes, it started working